# Swift: Populate UITableView with JSON data?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift

I've looked around for days, and can't figure out how to populate a `UITableView` with JSON data. I'm appending values to a `recommendedTitles` array and a `recommendedThumbnails` array, which I can associate between the two using an index.

I'm not getting any errors, just not getting any results. Am I missing something or doing this incorrectly?

```
class RecommendationCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var recommendationTitle: UILabel!

}

class SongViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var recommendedTitles = [String]()
    var recommendedImages = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

                let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&q=\(searchTerm)&maxResults=1&key=AIzaSyD7PxAoq0O5hUxx775l_E_mnowlU4cUfcI")

                let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!,  completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

                    if error != nil {

                        println(error)

                    } else {

                        let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

                            if let items = jsonResult["items"] as? NSArray {

                            // yada yada yada...

                                self.recommendedTitles.append(title)
                                self.recommendedImages.append(thumbnail)

                 })
                     newTask.resume()
    }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return recommendedTitles.count
        }


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            var songCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("songCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RecommendationCell

            songCell.recommendationTitle.text = recommendedTitles[indexPath.row]

            return songCell
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks reasonable. The one thing I notice is that you're not calling your tableView's reloadData() method once the JSON is done downloading.

Here's what I think is going on:

You start an async download in your viewDidLoad. That returns immediately, before the data has downloaded.

Your table view calls it's data source methods to see how many sections of data and rows/section are available. It is told there is no data.

Then your completion code fires, but the table view still thinks there's no data. If you add a reloadData() call at the end of your completion block, the table view will call your data source methods again, discover that there is now data to display, and draw your contents.

Comment: That did work, however the table view takes a full 10 seconds to load, unless I manually start scrolling. Then it instantly appears. Is there any way to load this as soon as it's ready?

Comment: Hey Duncan can I get a follow-up on this?